# Error inflating class fragment, when a map fragment is added to activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I am able to open the map fragment for the first time when I click on the Action bar icon, search for a location, add a marker at the location and add the location name to the list view on clicking the marker. But when I click on the action bar icon again to search for another place my app crashes. Please help, I have gone through other similar questions on So but nothing worked. Thanks in advance.

Main Activity

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener{

GoogleMap mMap;
private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 14;
public static ArrayList<String> myPlaces = new ArrayList<String>();
public static String location;
public ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_addPlaces:
            setContentView(R.layout.map_fragment);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public boolean initMap(){

    if(mMap==null){
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
    }
    return(mMap!=null);
}

private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom){
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat,lng);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
    mMap.moveCamera(update);
}

public void geoLocate(View v) throws IOException {
//        hideSoftKeyboard(v);

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);

    location = et.getText().toString();
    if (location.length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    Address add = list.get(0);
    String locality = add.getLocality();
    Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    double lat = add.getLatitude();
    double lng = add.getLongitude();

    gotoLocation(lat, lng, DEFAULT_ZOOM);

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .title(location)
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
    mMap.addMarker(options);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

}


    public boolean onMarkerClick (Marker marker){
        PlaceholderFragment list1 = new PlaceholderFragment();
        myPlaces.add(location);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container,list1)
                .commit();

        return false;
    }



public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayAdapter<String> mPlacesAdapter;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ArrayAdapter mPlacesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_places,
                R.id.list_item_places_textview,
                MainActivity.myPlaces);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_Places);
        listView.setAdapter(mPlacesAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Map fragment layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_subtitle_bottom_margin_material"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/abc_action_bar_subtitle_bottom_margin_material">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Location:"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:ems="10">

    <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="GO"
        android:onClick="geoLocate"/>


    </LinearLayout>


<fragment

    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
    map:cameraTargetLat="17.422245"
    map:cameraTargetLng="78.382000"
    map:cameraZoom="10"/>
```

ListView Layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView_Places"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the log of your crash which can indicate which line causes.